# JMeter: How can I get JSON value?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to test value of numFound and needs to be non zero.  I have following [image]

and I have tried following 
[image]

I get following errors
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the case of letters in variable name is important: `$..numFound` instead of `$..numfound`. Also remember that JSON path returns a valid JSON array, so it will look like this: `[148]`.

Comment: it work with numFound. Thank you!  what do I write in Expected Value text box where I want to say it should not be null.

Comment: for example it can be a "Response assertion" with "Matches" condition and regex like this: `\[[0-9]{1,}\]` (`[` followed by at least 1 digit, followed by `]`)